# Qt Some ASCII Missing Only on Certain Machine

Tags: qt, ascii, qtextedit

I have a problem with a QTextEdit. When I compile and run on my development environment from QtCreator in either debug or release modes, the text edit displays characters just fine. They all show up perfectly. Additionally, if I copy all of the dependent dll's (I'm on Windows) into a folder and run the release version from there, everything still displays correctly.

However, when I take the dir I just constructed in the last step and copy it to another machine, not all characters show up correctly. Only some of them show up. They are all ASCII characters, which come from an on-screen QWERTY keyboard. The text edit is where the characters are displayed for the on-screen keyboard. When the widget containing both the text edit and the QWERTY keyboard is closed, the text is copied out of the text edit and into a new text edit, where the ASCII characters show up fine.

for this quirky text edit, it seems that only certain characters are not showing. The same characters that show always show, and the same characters that do not show always do not show.

Assuming I've made this clear enough (it's tough to describe, so that's for your effort in advance), does anybody have an idea of how and why this is happening? How can it be resolved?

Comment: Maybe a font issue? Force your first text edit (the one that is acting weird) to use a font like "Arial". Does that make any difference? Can you post a screen shot that shows the problem, as well as the expected text? (Maybe there is a pattern.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a font issue. Perhaps the font that is being used in the text box is missing on the target computer or is corrupt. Force your first text edit (the one that is acting weird) to use a font like "Arial". Does that make any difference?

Comment: Forcing the text edit to use the same fonts as the other textual controls that do not experience problems resolved the issue. Thanks.